# how to implement python asyncio tcp server with multithreading mode

Tags: python, multithreading, tcp, python-asyncio

there is a simple echo tcp server example in http://asyncio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tcp_echo.html

it is implemented based on coroutine. the coroutine 'handle_echo' is running in main thread. I wonder if I can make the 'handle_echo' run in different thread like this:

```
def handle_echo(reader, writer):
    # I can't use await here, guess because it is not coroutine.
    data = await reader.read(100) 
    message = data.decode()
    addr = writer.get_extra_info('peername')
    print("Received %r from %r" % (message, addr))

    print("Send: %r" % message)
    writer.write(data)
    await writer.drain()

    print("Close the client socket")
    writer.close()


def call_in_background(target, *args):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    if callable(target):
        return loop.run_in_executor(executor, target, args[0], args[1])
    raise TypeError("target must be a callable, "
                    "not {!r}".format(type(target)))

async def handle_echo_wrapper(reader, writer):
    call_in_background(handle_echo, reader, writer)
```

the code looks quite wired. and I can't use 'await' in 'handle_echo' because it not coroutine any more.

so my question is, is it necessary to make asyncio tcp server in multithreading mode?e.g. create a worker thread pool according to number of CPU, and handle each client in a different thread. my concern is single thread and coroutine based server would be blocked by some not well code clients, is it possible? I try to prove it but not successful

Comment: What's the point of threads if you have async? I think I don't understand the use case well enough.

Comment: so what should be the correct TCP server IO model?e.g. if I have  4 cores CPU, should I create one IO event loop and process client handler in 4 threads or should I create four IO event loop and process each client handler by asyncio coroutine?

Comment: I just feel my understanding of IO model is wrong. IO bound task should be fine in single thread. it doesn't need multithreading.

Comment: Yes, you won't gain anything by distributing clients and coroutines that handle them between threads. Context switching is very slow, but switching coroutines is really fast.
You're better off using one thread, and running CPU-heavy tasks in a ProcessPoolExecutor.